# Change the maximum attachment size for Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

How do you change the default maximum attachment size for Visual Studio Online (default is around 4mb)?

In on-premise TFS 2015 you can change the maximum attachment size by using the method described in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400780.aspx.

This does, however, not apply when using hosted Visual Studio Online. The ConfigurationSettingsService.asmx service is only accessible from localhost, which of course is not possible when using Visual Studio Online.

I have tried to find the option in the configuration of Visual Studio Online but without any luck.

Comment: Default attachment size for VSO is around 28mb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the web service itself is accessible and works as expected. It is only the test form which is only available for requests from the local machine. You can use any tool to send proper calls, for example, [Postman Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop).

The test form, however, can help you identify the correct format of the request. Note that it should be POST request for either web method.

Here is the result of a call to `GetMaxAttachmentSize` (Ctrl + right click the image to see a larger version in a separate tab):

[image]

And this is how a `SetMaxAttachmentSize` call might look:

[image]

Now if you run the `GetMaxAttachmentSize` call again, it will return the new value for the max size - the one you've just set.

Note that the URL is identical in both requests. The name of the method and the parameters (if any) are passed in the request body.

Finally, I didn't have to authenticate somehow explicitly for this to work. I suspect that's because I've been logged in to my VSO account while running these samples.