# OpsHub migration utility failure due to large file attachment

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trialling the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility and have hit a problem with a large file attached.  I have since removed the attachment but asking the utility to retry doesn't progress.  Any ideas would be a great help.  Error message below....

OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed Save WorkItem. Server Error : The file you are trying to upload (10620.pdf) exceeds the supported file upload size (29 MB(s)). Instead of uploading the file, add the file to version control or to the team project web site, and then link the file to the work item.

Comment: Hi John,
In the free version of utility, if attachment are deleted at source TFS  then through retry it will not start migrating, for that you need to delete the target project and have to start migration from scratch. We have our paid version of utility where recovery of failure is supported. To get more information for our paid utility, you can reach out to sales@opshub.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by VSO attachment size limitation. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637399/change-the-maximum-attachment-size-for-visual-studio-online) to change the maximum attachment size for VSO.

Comment: Thanks Eddie.  Authentication didn't just work for me like it did in the other answer.  I enabled alternative authentication in VSO so I could use basic auth temporarily and managed to do the update.  Thank you.